# How to align text by adding spaces between words in java?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programme {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        method1(args[0],args[1],args[2]);

    }
    public static void method1(String file, String n, String m)throws 
Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
        String text = "";
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        text += sc.nextLine().trim()+" ";
        }    
            while (text.length() > Integer.parseInt(n)) {
                int idx = text.lastIndexOf(" ", Integer.parseInt(n));
                System.out.println(text.substring(0, idx));
                text = text.substring(idx + 1);
            }
            System.out.println(text.trim());


    }    
}
```

This is a code that receives a text file, n and m. If text file looks for example:

```
01 23 456 789 012 3 4 
56 78 9 0 12 34 56 789.
```

And the programme receives "n" as "12", then the programme will print the output as:

```
01 23 456
789 012 3 4
56 78 9 0 12
34 56 789.
```

Because it will limit each line to "n" letters.

Now what I don't know is how should I make the programme check if the third parameter "m" equals "set", and if it does it aligns the lines by inserting as many spaces as possible that the width of each row is EXACTLY n; while increasing the number of spaces evenly between words.

For example upper text file output with m as "set" would be:

```
01   23  456
789  012 3 4
56 78 9 0 12
34  56  789.
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this output?

Comment: Use the [String.format()](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/) method to align your output.